# Can Wordpress Drop-ins be given their own directory?

Tags: plugins, cache, wp-config

[Drop-in files](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/), like advanced-cache.php or object-cache.php, sit in the root of the wp-content directory.

Is it possible to give drop-ins in their own subdirectory of wp-content instead?

Looking at `_get_dropins()` in wp-admin/includes/plugins.php there are no filters to set the path to the drop-in files. Also, looking at `wp_plugin_directory_constants()` in wp-includes/default-constants.php there are no constants set specific to drop-ins (as of 3.8.1).

Comment: It looks like "not". Why do you need to?

Comment: Drop-ins, like [Memcached Object Cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/memcached/), are not upgradable in the admin and are tough to keep under version control.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to give drop-ins in their own subdirectory of
>   wp-content instead?

No, it is not possible without editing the core WordPress code.